# Redshift ignores whitespace when selecting distinct values from text column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Redshift appears to be ignoring trailing whitespace in `text` columns (really `varchar(256)`) in table when I attempt to run a `select distinct` on a given column.

Using a CTE, I get expected behavior:

```
dataeng=# with x as (select 'asdf'::text as y union all select 'asdf '::text as y) select distinct y from x;
   y
-------
 asdf
 asdf
(2 rows)
```

But once the data is inserted into a table, redshift can't tell the difference between the two values:

```
dataeng=# create table whitespace_test (y text);
CREATE TABLE
dataeng=# insert into whitespace_test values ('asdf'), ('asdf ');
INSERT 0 2
dataeng=# select distinct y from whitespace_test;
  y
------
 asdf
(1 row)
```

Even though it hasn't lost the trailing space:

```
dataeng=# select distinct '"' || y || '"' from whitespace_test;
 ?column?
----------
 "asdf"
 "asdf "
(2 rows)
```

I could certainly appreciate redshift actively sanitizing inputs, but I'd like to know about it and have control over it.

PostgreSQL 10 behaves as expected and does not exhibit this bug.

**Is this expected behavior, or have I uncovered a bug in redshift?**

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html) "*Trailing spaces in VARCHAR and CHAR values are treated as semantically insignificant when values are compared.*"

Comment: That is definitely interesting - so then my question would become "why does that same behavior not occur when a CTE is used instead of data in the underlying table?"

Comment: Interesting, my guess is that the CTE is executing on the leader node only (because no table is referenced), whereas the table processing is on the compute nodes. we know there are differences in what runs between the 2 node types. You may want to email AWS with this finding, they will most likely update the documentation.

Comment: @RyanTuck . . . I think this is more likely a bug in Postgres.  The trailing spaces should be ignored.

Comment: Similar to: [Why Redshift automatically trims varchar column when joining?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53569896/174777)

Comment: "An attempt to store a longer string into a column of these types results in an error, unless the extra characters are all spaces (blanks), in which case the string is truncated to the maximum length." interesting!